# Jquery Email regex validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I am using Jquery email Regex for validation as below:

> @"^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'*+-/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))).)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))$"

Not sure why it does not allow for uppercase?! If email address should not contain any upper case or anything is wrong here.

Comment: That's an ugly regular expression, you should look at html5 and also jquery form validation plugin if you want better syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everywhere you have an occurence of `[a-z]` character class, simply change it into `[a-zA-Z]`

(or specify the *case insensitive* flag/modifier `i` in your regexp)

Comment: Using the `i` flag is probably the least painful approach in this case.

Comment: yep, indeed the flag is the simpler solution

Comment: Thanks, but wondering why Jquery just validate lowercase for eamil addresses?

Comment: there's no Jquery in what you posted. that is only a PCRE pattern, nothing more, nothing less :)

Comment: @patricgh: what you posted is a string, too, not a RegExp object (yet), perhaps when the constructor is called `i` is passed as a second argument, to make the expression case-insensitive